# Dart Generics - type is not a subtype

Tags: generics, dart, subtype

I'm getting a runtime error from a Dart generic function:

```
 Widget card = widget.cardBuilder(item);
```

Which generates:

```
 type '(Contact) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '(DeletableItem) => Widget'
```

The Contact class is defined as

```
class Contact
implements DeletableItem
{
```

I then have a method:

```
 class UndoableListView<T extends DeletableItem>
 {
      List<T> children;
      final Widget Function(T item) cardBuilder;
```

And this is where the runtime error occurs

```
 Widget buildItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
 T item = children[index];
 Widget card = widget.cardBuilder(item);   <<<<< error thrown here.
```

I'm clearly mis-understanding something with how generics work.

Contact clearly extends DeleteableItem.

So what have I done wrong?

Comment: The issue is not that `Contact` doesn't implement `DeletableItem`, but rather that the whole function itself has a different signature since `(Contact) => Widget` cannot be cast to `(DeletableItem) => Widget`. Without seeing more code, it's hard to propose a fix. Can you show the context in which `buildItem` is being used?

Comment: The code is extracted from a rather large app. The intent is to pass in a list of Deleteable item to a list and have the list callback the builder to generate a card from the item. I'm confused as to way it can't be cast given that the Contact is of type Deleteable?

Comment: Any updates on this? I am getting the same error, I dont understand how Contract is not a subtype of DeletablItem even tho, well, it is!

Comment: Nothing here says that `Contact` is not a subtype of `DeletableItem`, but that the *function type* `Widget Function(Contact)` is not a subtype of the function type `Widget Function(DeletableItem)`. Function types are *contravariant* in their parameter types (a function type can only a subtype of another function type if the parameter types of the first function are *supertypes* of the parameter types of the second function). So, this is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

`Contact` extends `DeletableItem`, and is a subtype of it.

Functions are *contravariant* in their parameters, so

```dart
Widget Function(Contact)
```

is *not* a subtype of

```dart
Widget Function(DeletableItem)
```

In fact, it's the other way around.

Functions act that way because subtyping means substitutability.
You can use a `Contact` anywhere a `DeletableItem` is needed (because it implements the entire `DeletableItem` interface), so `Contact` is a subtype of `DeletableItem`.

You can use a `Widget Function(DeletableItem)` anywhere a `Widget Function(Contact)` is needed, because you can call that function with any `Contact` (and it returns a `Widget` as expected). So `Widget Function(DeletableItem)` is a subtype of `Widget Function(Contact)`.

Dart generics are *covariant*, even though it's not always sound.

That means that a `UndoableListView<Contact>` is a subtype of `UndoableListView<DeletableItem>`.

The problem comes up because the `cardBuilder` field uses the class type parameter contravariantly in the function type,

```dart
      final Widget Function(T item) cardBuilder;
```

So, when you do:

```dart
UndoableListView<DeletableItem> list = UndoableListView<Contact>();
var builder = list.cardBuilder;
```

you get an error.
The `list.cardBuilder` expression has a *static type* of `Widget Function(DeletableItem)`, but a run-time type of `Widget Function(Contact)`, which is not a subtype of the static type. That's a type soundness problem, one the compiler is aware of, and it inserts a type check to ensure that the `builder` variable won't end up with an invalidly typed value.

And that check throws.

Comment: How to fix this error?